# wc -l giving integer expression expected error

Tags: bash

I know the output isn\t being recognized as integer but I fail to understand why? The file has more than 5 lines.

```
$ if [ "$(wc -l test.txt)" -gt "$5" ]; then
            echo changes found;
           else
            echo  No changes found;
           fi

bash: [: 6 test.xml: integer expression expected
No changes found
```

Comment: I guess that `$5`, the fifth command line argument, evaluates to an empty string, thereby confusing test

Comment: ... or to another non-integer.

Comment: Simply use `$(wc -l <test.txt)` to avoid printing name of file!

Comment: the error message references the left side of the comparison as the string `6 test.xml` (the output from the `wc` call; and assuming you meant to use `test.xml` instead of `test.txt` in the example code) and hence the rest of the error message `integer expression expected` (ie, `6 test.xml` is not an integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this:

```
wc -l test.txt
```

With following result:

```
5 test.txt
```

So the result contains a number, followed by the name of the file.

You can solve it like this:

```
wc -l test.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

This only gives the number.

So, you might change your code into:

```
$ if [ "$(wc -l test.txt  | awk '{print $1}')" -gt "$5" ]; then
```

... and now correct:

```
$ if [ $(wc -l test.txt  | awk '{print $1}') -gt 5 ]; then
```

Comment: `wc -l < test.txt` also works. `wc` doesn't print the file name if it's stdin.

Comment: All this works great until it goes into if loop.

$ if [ "$(wc -l test.txt  | awk '{print $1}')" -gt "$5" ]; then echo Y; else echo X; fi
bash: [: : integer expression expected
X


$ wc -l test.txt  | awk '{print $1}'
6

Comment: @Oxycash: I removed the double quotes and replaced `$5` (the fifth parameter) by `5` (the number five). Is it going better now?

Comment: @Dominique that did it finally!